# Converting for into jQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Really new to JS and wondering if someone knew how i can change the following into using jQuery each:

current:

```
for (var i in basket){
    var item = basket[i];
    var row = "<tr><td><img src='" + item.image + "' class='thumbnail'/></td><td>" + item.title + "</td><td>" + item.sku + "</td><td>&pound;" + item.price + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#' class='button primary small delete-item' data-item='"+ i +"'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
    $(".basket-content").append(row);
}
```

attempted:

```
$.each(function(i, basket){
  for (var i in basket){
    var item = basket[i];
    var row = "<tr><td><img src='" + item.image + "' class='thumbnail'/></td><td>" + item.title + "</td><td>" + item.sku + "</td><td>&pound;" + item.price + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#' class='button primary small delete-item' data-item='"+ i +"'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
    $(".basket-content").append(row);
  }
});
```

Comment: The reason im wanting to do this as its not passing JSLint validation, it does work but i need it to validate.

Comment: Let me update with a better example

Comment: What is JSLint complaining about?

Comment: Was a few things, i managed to get it all sorted though... most needed exceptions in JSLint but it was complaining about using  for for(){ for some reason but all sorted now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `$.each` is the array/object you want to iterate over. The arguments to the function are the index and the element (so you don't need to assign `item` yourself).

```
$.each(basket, function(i, item) {
    var row = "<tr><td><img src='" + item.image + "' class='thumbnail'/></td><td>" + item.title + "</td><td>" + item.sku + "</td><td>&pound;" + item.price + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#' class='button primary small delete-item' data-item='"+ i +"'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
    $(".basket-content").append(row);
});
```

Comment: Yep that worked, twisted up something else but that was not working anyway so will raise another issue for that as im stuck :) but overall working mate thanks very much!

Comment: Actually running in JSLint im getting: Unused 'i'.
    $.each(basket, function(i, product) { any ideas?

Comment: Its ok, i removed it and worked still haha thanks again for your help!

Comment: I don't know why it's saying that, since you have `+ i +` in the middle of the `row` assignment.

Comment: Yea strange... anyway all verified in JSLint and working... i  had to go through and make some tweaks as some of the each was returning undefined but got those all sorted. Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example to make a array loop in jquery

```js
var array = new Array();
array.push('test');
array.push('test2');
$.each(array, function(i, basket){
  console.log('key', i);
   console.log('value', basket);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, ill give it a go as have a few on the page... give me 5 minutes make but think i know what you mean.